# gsub across multiple lines in R (dotall)

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Is it possible to invoke the dotall expression with `gsub` in R?  Basically, I am trying to extract a section of text that spans multiple lines.  Consider the following as an example:

```
eg.df <- c("----------", " ", "keep", " ", "keep this too", " ", "----------", " ", 
   "Delete this line and everything after", "Delete this one too", 
   " ", "And delete this one")
```

I want to use lines 7-9 as my pattern to match.  I want to delete those lines AND everything that follows, up until the end of the file.

```
[1] "----------"                           
[2] " "                                    
[3] "keep"                                 
[4] " "                                    
[5] "keep this too"                        
[6] " "                                    
[7] "----------"                           
[8] " "                                    
[9] "Delete this line and everything after"
[10] "Delete this one too"                  
[11] " "                                    
[12] "And delete this one"
```

So, the resulting output would be:

```
[1] "----------"                           
[2] " "                                    
[3] "keep"                                 
[4] " "                                    
[5] "keep this too"                        
[6] " "
```

Comment: Probably just `eg.df[cumsum(grepl("-", eg.df)) == 0]` or something similar. `gsub` has nothing to do here really because you have a vector rather a single string.

Comment: That would work, but I have other lines with `---------` that need to be retained.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just updated the example

Comment: So how do you decide that you want to delete everything after the second `----` and not the first?

Comment: @BrianP Is it the last pattern from which you wanted to delete

Comment: I have thousands of lines of text, including thousands of occurrences of `-----`.  The target I am seeking is a unique string.  I want to identify that specific string, eliminate the preceding `-----`, and eliminate everything that comes after the target string.

Comment: @akrun:  Exactly.  Sorry that I wasn't clear.

Comment: @BrianP I updated the code based on your new example. Hope it helps

Comment: @BrianP, your data makes no sense, if they are "lines" then why are they separated individually into a vector?

Comment: @hwnd this format is what you get from `readLines` so I'm guessing it could be from that. The entire question perplexes me, however

Comment: If you have thousands of `-----` so what does it mean "*I want to identify that specific string, eliminate the preceding -----, and eliminate everything that comes after the target string*". That makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: Line 9 is my unique string I want to identify.  I want to delete that string, and everything that comes after it.  I also want to delete the preceding `-----`.  However, I do not want to delete the other occurrences of `-----`.

Comment: Ok, that is clear but in reality do you have a vector of strings like this or is this a very long string???????

Comment: I'm actually using readLines on the original text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
  strsplit(sub('-+, +,[A-Za-z]+[^-]+$', '', 
         paste(eg.df, collapse= ',')), ',')[[1]]
  #[1] "----------"    " "             "keep"          " "            
  #[5] "keep this too" " "
```

Or as @hwnd commented,

```
  strsplit(sub('-+[^-]+\\z', '', paste(eg.df, collapse = '_'), 
                      perl=T), '_')[[1]]
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I didn't understand what the OP wants. Or in other words, how is that conceptually different from what I proposed?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think the OP wants to delete all those lines if there is a text string with pattern '-----', then comes  ' ', and then some text string.  So, what I did was, paste the `eg.df` with delimiter as `,` and use the `lookarounds` in `sub` that follows those patterns and replace it with `''`.  Lastly, `strsplit` the string based on `,`.  I am guessing this may be the case, though not certain

Comment: I would use `strsplit(sub('-+[^-]+\\z', '', paste(eg.df, collapse = '_'), perl=T), '_')[[1]]`

Comment: @akrun - sorry, I didn't see that it was edited to reflect the changes I made.